# C# destructor not called even after code scope + GC?

Tags: c#, testing, garbage-collection, nunit, destructor

I've got a simple test code in Nunit+.net core 2.0 under VS2019:

```
public class Tests
{
    public static int i = 0;
    class First
    {
        ~First()
        {
            i += 1;
            Console.WriteLine("First's destructor is called.");
        }
    }

    class Second : First
    {
        ~Second() { i += 10; Console.WriteLine("Second's destructor is called."); }
    }

    class Third : Second
    {
        ~Third() { i += 100; Console.WriteLine("Third's destructor is called."); }
    }
    [Test]
    public static void Test()
    {
        {
            Third t = new Third();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        System.GC.Collect();
        Assert.AreEqual(111, i);
    }
}
```

It always fails, while I found finally i=0, and the destructors are called right after Test(). But you can see the "t" is in a code block, and is invalid after the code block, and I also called

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

before my "Assert".

Why destructor is not called even after GC? How to fix my code to make the test pass?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need at least a call to `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers` in there. If you're in a Debug build, it's probably also holding onto `t` for debugging reasons: the scope of a variable is almost entirely unrelated to when it's available for GC

Comment: In general, in C#, there is rarely a need to write a finalizer. Writing good finalizes is very hard. If you want deterministic finalization (i.e., you want cleanup code to run at a specific time) look up `IDisposable`, `using` and the Dispose pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **using** statement and the **IDisposable** **interface** instead destructor;

```
 public class Tests
{
    public static int i = 0;
    class First : IDisposable
    {
        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            i += 1; Console.WriteLine("First's Dispose is called.");
        }
    }

    class Second : First
    {
        public override void Dispose()
        {
            i += 10; Console.WriteLine("Second's Dispose is called.");
            base.Dispose();
        }
    }

    class Third : Second
    {
        public override void Dispose()
        {
            i += 100; Console.WriteLine("Third's Dispose is called.");
            base.Dispose();
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        using (Third t = new Third()) {
            Console.WriteLine("Now everything will be ok, after leaving this block");
            Console.WriteLine("t object will be dispose");
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        System.GC.Collect();
        Assert.AreEqual(111, i);
    }
}
```

You can call ***System.GC.Collect()*** but it is not matter. The destructor will not be call immediately as you expect. (In above code you don't need ***System.GC.Collect()***)

[image]

It is strange to me why Microsoft does not make this clearer, instead of the old definition **"Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations."** which leads developers to think they should expect an immediate result and ***GC.Collect()*** should **wait** for garbage collection to be complete before it returns?!

[GC.Collect Method(System) - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.collect?view=netframework-4.8)

Even more strange to me is that the code they give as an example for using of ***GC.Collect()*** don't work as they claim, for the same reason. You can try yourself by commenting ***GC.Collect();*** line. I don't know, maybe they just don't update their documents as often. Maybe the situation was different before with ***GC.Collect()***?! *GC.CollectRequest()* would be a more appropriate name for this function, if you ask me.

[image: Strange example code on Microsoft page for GC.Collect()]

P.s. I'm new to C# so please, excuse me if I say things that do not fully understand or something I'm wrong in the code I write.

Answer (score 0):

Call `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` after `GC.Collect()`

The finalizers (not destructors) run as background tasks asynchronously, so after you call `GC.Collect()` and reach the assertion statement the finalizers are not guaranteed to have finished.

Comment: I added this line after GC.Collect(), but still it doesn't work, Assert still fails because of "i=0".

Comment: Are you running in Release or Debug?

Comment: In debug mode. Thanks.

Comment: I also tried to run it undre release mode. Same result

Comment: Strange. I'm running the exact same code in NUnit and the test passes. Maybe extract what's inside the curly braces to a different method and see if it helps?

Comment: Or maybe keep the reference in the same scope but change the reference to `null` before calling `GC.Collect()`?